# Understanding the units of cosmic string number density

Tags: cosmology, units, si-units, absolute-units, cosmic-string

I am reading this old paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.6637.pdf and trying to work out the units in equation 63. It gives the number density of cosmic strings in the radiation era as

$$
\frac{n(\ell,t)}{a^3(t)}\approx\frac{0.18}{t^{3/2}(\ell+\Gamma G\mu t)^{5/2}}
$$

with $n$ the number density, $a$ the scale factor, $t$ coordinate time, $\ell$ the loop size, $\Gamma$ the ratio of power radiated between GWs and EM and $G\mu$ the characteristic string tension.

I expect the LHS to have units of $1/m^3$, as the scale factor is unitless. Making the substitution $t\rightarrow ct$ and $G\mu\rightarrow\frac{G\mu}{c^2}$ in order to convert $s$ to $m$ and $\frac{m^2}{s^2}$ to unitless turns the units of the RHS into a quantity with units $1/m^4$, which doesn't reconcile with the LHS.

What mistake am I making converting back to SI?

Comment: Please do not link directly to pdf or documents when an abstract page is available.  Abstract pages are the preferred link to a paper where possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n=\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 N}{\mathrm{d}V\mathrm{d}\ell};$$
integrate over $\ell$ to get something with number density units.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense. Where did you see this in the text?

Comment: It's only suggested by the early manipulations, but a previous article [1101.5173](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.5173) by the same authors gives the definition explicitly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.